# complement of a subvariety by an algebraic element

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y$ be an affine variety of $k^n$, defined by polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_s \subset A = k[y_1,\dots,y_n]$, i.e., $Y=V(f_1,\dots,f_s)$ where $k$ is algebraically closed. Now let $g \in A$ such that 
$f_1,\dots,f_s,g$ are algebraically dependent over $k$. Is it then possible 
that the complement of the variety $W=V(f_1,\dots,f_s,g)$ in $Y$ is of infinite cardinality, i.e., the set $Y \setminus W$ to have infinite cardinality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

For example, let $k=\mathbb{C}$, $A = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $f = (x - y)(x - y - 1)$, $g = x - y$.

Then
\begin{align*}
&\bullet\;\;f,g\text{ are algebraically dependent, since }f = g^2 - g\\[6pt]
&\bullet\;\;Y=V(f) = \{(z,z) \mid z \in \mathbb{C}\} \cup \{(z,z-1) \mid z \in \mathbb{C}\}\\[6pt]
&\bullet\;\;W = V(f,g) = V(g) = \{(z,z) \mid z \in \mathbb{C}\}\\[6pt]
&\bullet\;\;Y \setminus W = \{(z,z-1) \mid z \in \mathbb{C}\}\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

so $Y \setminus W$ is infinite.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Let $n=2$, $f_1=x$, $g=x-1$. Then as $W\cap Y$ is empty, $Y\setminus W= Y\cong \mathbb{A}^1_k$ which is infinite.